# How to make python stop looking if there is a negative value?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict:

```
ff = {("Tom Brady",45678 ): [[456.0, 4050.0], [0.32, 5.6]]}
```

and

```
f = {("Tom Brady",45678 ): [[456.0, 4050.0, -1000.0], [0.32, 5.6, 4.56]]}
```

I have this code:

```
def find_neg (client_list: dict[tuple[str, int], list[list[float]]], client: tuple[str, int]) -> int

for a in client_list[client][0]: 
    if a>0:
      return 2
    if a<0
      return 1
```

the problem with this code is that when there is no negative value, python gives me an error telling me it cannot be NoneType. I want the code to give me an answer if there is a negative, but instead it only gives me an error.

Comment: you should give the full backtrace and Ident your code correctly.

Comment: ok I will edit that, just a min.

Comment: Is the function supposed to return 1 if any value is less than 0, else 2?

Comment: So your function returns 2 if if finds a positive value, 1 if it finds a negative value, or `None` if it only sees 0s. There's technically nothing wrong with the *function*, only in the assumptions you make about what it returns. (That is, you are ignoring the possibility that it returns `None`.)

Answer (score 1):

Your current logic is:

```py
def help_find_neg(lst: list[float]):
    for element in lst: 
        if element > 0:
            return 2
        if element < 0:
            return 1
        # and if element == 0: go to the next element
```

If your `lst` consists only of zeros, the function will skip all of them (and return `None`).

This might be the reason behind your `NoneType` error.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the list of lists (the value in your dictionaries) into one big list, and then use list comprehension to create a new list that only holds the negative numbers. If the length of this list comprehension result is bigger than 0, then you have negative numbers in any of the lists that is in the value of your dictionary.

```py
def find_neg (client_list: dict[tuple[str, int], list[list[float]]], client: tuple[str, int]) -> int:
    big_list = sum(client_list[client], [])
    negatives = [i for i in big_list if i < 0]
    if len(negatives) > 0:
        return True
    return False
```

(the `sum` is a little trick to create one list out of a list of lists).

As per comments; if you only need to know if there **was** a negative number (and you will never need to know what number(s) those were), you could simplify:

```py
def find_neg (client_list: dict[tuple[str, int], list[list[float]]], client: tuple[str, int]) -> int:
    big_list = sum(client_list[client], [])
    for i in big_list:
        if i < 0:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: This does a lot of unnecessary work if the first element in the list is negative. There's no point finding *all* the negatives if the return value only depends on finding *a* negative.

Comment: Sure, you could make it simpler by using a for-loop that returns as soon as one of the elements is negative.